# How to make div boxes same height as each other, while aligning list items within

Tags: html, css, list, divider

My site consists of 8 divs (green boxes) which contain an image and either 3 or 4 list items. Each list item contains text only. My problem is that the divs (boxes) are not the same height for 2 reasons:  (1)  One div may contain an additional list item which pushes the other items down... or (2) I have no idea, because even when all 3 green divs in a row have the same amount of list items, they're still not the same height (See bullet #2 below screenshot).

I simply need all divs in a row to have the **same height** no matter the amount of list items or whatever.

The demo site is [here](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/demo.html).

This screenshot shows the top row of divs, with a blue box identifying the problems.

[image: problem]

- **Problem 1:** Divs #1 and #2 differ in height because div #2 has an additional list
  item.
- **Problem 2:** Div #1 and #3 have virtually the same text, yet their divs are
  not the same height either (close but different).

Ideally I'd like:

1. The red text to be placed atop the image above it, overlaying it.
2. Have all list items with a div ALIGNED vertically with adjacent divs.

Here is what I'd like it to look like (red text changed to green for visibility:

[image: solution]

Here is a div's HTML:

```
    <a href="http:adfadfafl">

             <div class="block personal fl">

                <!-- CONTENT -->
                <div class="content">
                    <p class="price">
    <p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/2.jpg)"></p>
                    </p>

                </div>
                <!-- /CONTENT -->
                <!-- FEATURES -->
                <ul class="features">
                <li class="redbox">MAKE THIS OVER IMAGE</li>
                <li class="titlebox">ldfadfadf </li>
                <li>ad ffadfa dfad f</li>
                <li>adf adfad </li>
                  </ul>

            </div>

      </a>
```

and it's CSS:

**Green Box**

```
.block{
    width: 30%;    
    margin: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 700px;
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;    
/*    border: 1px solid red;*/
}
```

**Red Line of Text:**

```
.redbox{margin-top: -2%; margin-bottom:-5%; color:red; font-weight:bold;}
```

**Top Line of Text**

```
.titlebox{margin-bottom:20%;}
```

**Bottom 2 Lines of Text**

```
.features li{
    padding:25px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**and the container the holds the list items with the div:**

```
.features{
    list-style-type: none;    
    background: #A1F997;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding:40px 12%;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Garamond;
}
```

Once again you can view my demo site [here](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/demo.html). Ideally need solution that works for IE7+ .Thank you all!

Comment: Use `height` instead of `min-height` and `max-height` in the CSS code.

Comment: Are you open to using JS? I have built a library called AlignJS which helps me a lot at work when I have this problem. https://github.com/jacksonv1lle/AlignJS

Comment: could you produced a cleaned up codepen, jsfiddle or even a code snippet as for a demo of yours that one can update easily

Comment: I've included a jsfiddle below, however the green div heights ARE equal in this fiddle for some reason. I included all 3 scripts  in the "JS" text area, perhaps this isn't the correct way. Why is my demo site in my question not showing even heights?  Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/02e0uhrx/

Comment: You need to set a height for all elements that should have exact height.

Comment: @Aradmey, are you telling me to change that for .block? Such as .block{
    width: 30%;    
    margin: 0 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height:700px; ....    Because that doesn't change anything

Comment: @cli can you give me an example using my code? I'm confused as to what you're meaning

Comment: @nova, okay for the fiddle , i rework a basic example in a code snippet in an answer below, no js involved for this 2 cases taken

Comment: I created this fiddle from your demo site: http://jsfiddle.net/vmLo9fe8/ There is no difference in height in this fiddle. How do you make text over image? You set `style="background-image:url(http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/2.jpg)"` to your text (class="redbox") Since there is no differnce in height in fiddle, it must be some JavaScript or something changing that height.

Answer (score 1):

if you look for lines of block of same height but different height allowed from a line to another  , `display:flex` or a trick with `inline-block` and `box-shadow` or even with the use absolute pseudo-elements could do it :

inline-block:

```css
body>div {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}
a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:0 0.5em 0;
  width:25%;
  background:lightgreen;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 0 lightgreen , 0 100px lightgreen  , 0 150px lightgreen ;
  border-top:1em solid white;
  padding:0.5em;}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

or flex:

```css
body>div {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  justify-content:center;
}
a {
  margin:0.5em 1%;
  width:27%;
  background:lightgreen;
  padding:0.5em;}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a>
    <div> 
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
      <p>line</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

these would a possibility via CSS, if all boxes must have same height ( height of the tallest), then javascript will be needed

Comment: Only boxes within the SAME row must have the SAME height. The solution must also work for IE7+ so I think FlexWrap won't work. Your first code snippet might work though, I'll try soon! Thanks

Comment: Ok I've applied your code, and everything looks good except that the second row is riding up into the first row. Div #4 should appear directly below Div#1 with a little space between the rows. Here's a codepen demo, please help!   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEoJKE

Comment: @Nova you could keep going with box shadow and filtering last-of-type with nth-child , and force boxes to stand on the left http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gbeNao

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, except that when I add more divs, the problem re-occurs further down. Check it out:  http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/index_main2.html

Comment: Wait.. If I edit the codepen then there is no issue when adding more divs. How come there *is* an issue on my demo site?  Here is the updated CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYXoYd  and here's the screenshot showing the problem on my server http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/screenshot1.png    Thanks!